# Not able to push a docker image to local registry (localstack)

Tags: docker, networking, wsl-2, localstack, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to push a docker image to a [LocalStack ECR](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/elastic-container-registry/). My setup is as follows:

- I am using a VSCode devcontainer from where I run my docker commands
  (docker.sock is mounted to that container)
- Docker Desktop runs under
  Windows with WSL2 support enabled, so containers actually run in WSL
- Both my devcontainer and the localstack container are in the same
  network

Here is my devcontainer.json:

```
{
    "name": "localstack base",

    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile",
        "context": "../",
    },

    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-outside-of-docker:1": { "version": "latest",  "moby": true },
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python:1" : {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/aws-cli:1": { "version": "latest" },
    },

    // to access localstack running on host
    "runArgs": ["--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway"],

    "containerEnv": {
        "LOCALSTACK_API_KEY": "${localEnv:LOCALSTACK_API_KEY}",
        "LOCALSTACK_HOST": "host.docker.internal",
    },

    "postCreateCommand": "pip install awscli-local",
}
```

Due to the `add-host` option, I am able to push to docker push `localhost:4510/my-repo:latest`. As I have setup the [LocalStack DNS Server](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/tools/transparent-endpoint-injection/dns-server/), one should be able to push to `localhost.localstack.cloud:4510/my-repo` as well. But this does not work. The weird thing is that it works if I do a push to localhost first:

```
vscode ➜ /workspaces/localstack-docker (master) $ docker push localhost:4510/my-repo:latest
The push refers to repository [localhost:4510/my-repo]
bac8c3444ad1: Pushed
f580243f0bd5: Pushed
0bde34c12f03: Pushed
a3a9343b131f: Pushed
283e9d842a8b: Pushed
7548033dbb18: Pushed
a90e3914fb92: Pushed
053a1f71007e: Pushed
ec09eb83ea03: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:5053df0363e29e6cf0c556a9a4e05ba0fd5426e4bda8197eb9e23c0c1c1fb155 size: 2206
vscode ➜ /workspaces/localstack-docker (master) $ docker push localhost.localstack.cloud:4510/my-repo:latest
The push refers to repository [localhost.localstack.cloud:4510/my-repo]
bac8c3444ad1: Layer already exists
f580243f0bd5: Layer already exists
0bde34c12f03: Layer already exists
a3a9343b131f: Layer already exists
283e9d842a8b: Layer already exists
7548033dbb18: Layer already exists
a90e3914fb92: Layer already exists
053a1f71007e: Layer already exists
ec09eb83ea03: Layer already exists
latest: digest: sha256:5053df0363e29e6cf0c556a9a4e05ba0fd5426e4bda8197eb9e23c0c1c1fb155 size: 2206
12:54 Uhr
2023-04-26 12:52:52 localstack-docker-localstack-1  | 2023-04-26T10:52:52.619  INFO --- [-functhread9] l.services.ecr.provider    : We got a push to my-repo with tag latest with manifest content type application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
2023-04-26 12:53:01 localstack-docker-localstack-1  | 2023-04-26T10:53:01.782  INFO --- [-functhread9] l.services.ecr.provider    : We got a push to my-repo with tag latest with manifest content type application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
```

Why is it not possible to push to `localhost.localstack.cloud:4510` in the first place?

Here is the `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack-pro:2.0.2

    ports:
      - "4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53"                # DNS config (only required for Pro)
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53/udp"            # DNS config (only required for Pro)
      - "127.0.0.1:443:443"              # LocalStack HTTPS Gateway (only required for Pro)
    environment:
      LOCALSTACK_API_KEY: ${LOCALSTACK_API_KEY}
```